# Point internet domain name to socketstream application/port

Tags: node.js, dns, socketstream

I am looking for guidelines for pointing 3 internet domains to 3 different socketstream 3.x applications.

Lets say i have three ss apps running,

99.99.99.1:4010, 99.99.99.1:4020, 99.99.99.1:4030

and i own 3 domains

www.myfirstdomain.com, www.myseconddomain.com, www.mythirddomain.com

What is the recommended approach for routing the domains to the applications? Somehow make ss recognize url headers or something? Three different ips on server? I probably need some routing module for node? What to change in ss /app.js ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a HTTP proxy, either using NGINX, or if you prefer using a Node.js-based solution, using the bouncy npm module https://github.com/substack/bouncy, or the node-http-proxy module https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy.

An example relating to your case could be this:

```
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

var server = bouncy(function (req, res, bounce) {
    if (req.headers.host === 'www.myfirstdomain.com') {
        bounce(4010);
    }
    else if (req.headers.host === 'www.myseconddomain.com') {
        bounce(4020);
    }
    else if (req.headers.host === 'www.myseconddomain.com') {
        bounce(4030);
    }
    else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end('no such host');
    }
});
server.listen(80);
```

Comment: Thank you Paul ! I will try it out when revisiting this project.